# Is there a rule for something like "footroom"?

Tags: portrait, composition, street-photography

I'm familiar with [headroom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headroom_%28photographic_framing%29) concept.

Is there rule of thumb for "footroom" (how much space to leave *beneath* the subject)?

I suppose the answer may differ depend on shooting style/purpose, so I limit the question
to full body portrait and street photography.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in general images are more pleasing when the feet are not cut off or exactly level with the bottom of the image.

But just as there is no definitive amount of headroom to leave, there is no definitive amount of footroom to leave, just what looks right for a particular image.

You will probably find that you need to leave more headroom that footroom.